# Need help with Peano inequality theorem

Tags: advice, peano-axioms

The following deals with Peano arithmetic
I have trouble dealing with inequalities

Working assumptions :

**6.22 Theorem** Let m  $\leqslant$ n denote the fact that m ∈ n or m = n. Then the relation is an order relation in ω.

**Prove there is no natural number k such that m<k<m+.**

I think by contradiction would be a good way

**Attempted proof**

m<k<m+ means m<k and k<m+

By 6.22 ,m<k implies m=k or m$\in$ k
and k<m+  implies k=m+ or k$\in$ m+

If m=k and k=m+ then m+=k+ and
k+=m+

But k+ can’t be m’s successor and m
simultaneously
thus there
is no natural
number k satisfying
the condition.
Help

Comment: Note that $\ m<k\ $ means $\ m\le k\ $ *but* $\ m\ne k\  $, or, in other words, given your definition of $\ m\le k\ $, $\ m<k\Leftrightarrow m\in k\ $.

Comment: If that is the case  m<k<-> $ m\in k $. by 6.22 $m \in k $ ; m$\subseteq$ k+